# return does not stops executing code inside request

Tags: node.js, express, request

i am using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package and it works but after performing request and sending status code to user it continues to execute code even though i use return. here is my code

```
request(longurl, {method: 'HEAD'}, function(error,response,body){
     if(error){
         return res.status(409).send({
             message: 'URL is not valid'
         })
     }
})
if(other_condition){
   return res.status(409).send({})
}
```

and it gives me

> (node:3040) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Can't set headers
> after they are sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `return` in a callback function. This is making that function return, but the outer function will continue execution. Perhaps your other_condition check should be inside the callback, and then you won't need the return statements.

```
request(longurl, {method: 'HEAD'}, function(error,response,body){
     if(error){
         res.status(409).send({
             message: 'URL is not valid'
         })
     } else if(other_condition){
         res.status(409).send({})
     }
})
```

Comment: @iLiA Ofcource it is a r8 solution. At least this solves your problem. Isn't it?

Comment: yeah it solves of course but i just asked if there was a better solution to be honest i do not like this style

Comment: @iLiA It's js `callback` style.If you want a better way, then you can check for `async-await` syntax.

Comment: i did it with async await but it sent default error message but i want to modify it so

Comment: If you want to modify it when using async-await, you can modify the error in the `catch` statement